# Best puzzles of 2022 Q3 (July - September)

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of)*

---

> What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the third quarter ( July / August / September ) 2022?

---

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of":**
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2022 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2022&month=7#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2022 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2022&month=7#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2022 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/07/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2022 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/07/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2022 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/07/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

<sub>Q: Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>
<sub>A: Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13653/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-first-quarter-2022) do something very similar.</sub>

<sub>Q: What's the point?</sub>
<sub>A1: To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
<sub>A2: To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
<sub>A3: To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

## [“IQ” puzzles seem to be flooding this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117419) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz)

One of the joys of the Monthly Topic Challenges (and before them, the Fortnightly ones...) is seeing how different puzzle setters interpret the brief. For me personally, this puzzle by @Amoz completely epitomised the spirit of the challenge, *and then some*.

It undeniably followed the brief, successfully parodying the IQ puzzle genre - and in a really creative and visual way. But (more than that) it really went above and beyond, involving 12 creative enigmatic mini-puzzles and an over-arching metapuzzle to tie them all together.

Each of the mini-puzzles gave a very pleasing head-scratch and a satisfying 'aha' moment when their answers were found, and identifying the secret theme that ran through all of these 'IQ' puzzles brought a smile to my face. A really pleasing puzzle to solve (ably explained by @MOehm in his excellent answer), and clearly very thoughtfully devised and presented - nicely done!